# detect which button is pressed sdk paypal

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

I need to detect which button is pressed to perform an action
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc7SL.jpg)

if it was pressed button paypal or button credit card
or exists some function to help me into sdk paypal

i use the code from documentation

```
paypal.Buttons({
style: {
  shape: 'rect',
  color: 'gold',
  layout: 'vertical',
  label: 'paypal',
  },
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            "purchase_units": [
            {
              "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": monto,
                "breakdown": {
                  "item_total": {
                    "currency_code": "USD",
                    "value": monto
                  }
                }
              },
              "items": [
                    {
                      "name": "Donacion",
                      "description": "Donacion a Inti Academy",

                      "unit_amount": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": monto
                      },
                      "quantity": "1",
                    },
              ],
            }
          ]
        });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
     return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
    
     });
    }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I tried to get the action from the class name of the credit button but it doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't the data in onApprove give you what you need?

Comment: I just need to detect which button was pressed

Comment: for another actions

Answer (score 0):

There is an onClick handler you can try, but as far as I know no information about *which* button was clicked is provided, just that one was.

Also, the button that was clicked does not determine which funding source the customer will ultimately pay with within PayPal.

And in any event, it does not matter, that is the point of using PayPal as a processor. All you need to worry about is that you received a completed PayPal payment; the billing and funding source information is all kept private to the payer, by design.